# Is this an implementation of Reinforcement learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, reinforcement-learning

I've written code in Python to replicate the results of a brief and simple paper about [reinforcement learning](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257744845_Testing_Different_Reinforcement_Learning_Configurations_for_Financial_Trading_Introduction_and_Applications).

A brief description of the problem: we have a generated time series of returns (that becomes the succession of states), a set of discrete actions (1,0,-1), and a linear approximation of the action-value function. So there is an offline learning algorithm that computes the action maximizing the action-value function approximator then computes the reward and receive the new state. Then it updates the parameters based on TD(0).

My question is here: is this enough to classify this as RL?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import random
import math 
from math import atan
from numpy import array
import statistics 

#preliminary functions: price to returns and an approximation of the gradient
def PtoR(x) :
    x_1=x[1:]
    x_0=x[:(len(x)-1)]
    xx=(x_1-x_0)/x_0
    return(xx)

def der(f, x, der_index=[]):
    # der_index: variable w.r.t. get gradient
    epsilon = 2.34E-11
    grads = []
    for idx in der_index:
       x_ = x.copy()
       x_[idx]+=epsilon

       grads.append((f(x_) - f(x))/epsilon)

    return grads


#generation of datas (time series)
beta,z=np.random.random(2).reshape(-1,1)

for i in range(1, 5001):
    a, b=np.random.randn(2)
    beta=np.append(beta,0.9*(beta[i-1])+b)
    z=np.append(z, z[i-1]+beta[i-1]+3*a)

data=np.exp(z/(max(z)-min(z)))
plt.plot(data)
ret=PtoR(data)


#possible actions
a=(1,0,-1)

#Action-value function approximator
def qfun(par):
   return(par[0]+atan(par[7])*par[1]+atan(par[8])*par[2]+atan(par[9])*par[3]+atan(par[10])*par[4]+atan(par[11])*par[5]+atan(par[12])*par[6])

#Inizialization of parameters
pars=np.random.random(7)
gamma=0.7
alpha=0.08

azione=(ret[0:5]>0)*1-1*(ret[0:5]<=0) #vector of initial actions arbitrary calculated, in order to star the process
returns=np.cumsum(azione*ret[0:5])   #vector of returns

i=5
for i in range(5, len(ret)):
    #State at t-1
    st=np.array((ret[i-5],ret[i-4],ret[i-3],ret[i-2], ret[i-1]))

    #decide what's the best action according to the qfun
    if(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(1,st)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(-1,st)))):
        if(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(1,st)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(0,st)))):
            az=array(1)
        else: az=array(0)
    elif(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(-1,st)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(0,st)))):
            az=array(-1)
    else: az=array(0)

    #epsilon-greedy exploration/exploitation
    azione=np.append(azione,np.random.choice(np.append(az,a),1,p=(0.94,0.02,0.02,0.02)))

    #receive state and reward at t
    st1=np.array((ret[i-4],ret[i-3],ret[i-2],ret[i-1], ret[i]))
    reward=np.mean(azione[(i-4):(i+1)]*st1)/statistics.stdev(azione[(i-4):(i+1)]*st1)

    #verify what would have been the best action
    if(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(1,st1)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(-1,st1)))):
        if(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(1,st1)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(0,st1)))):
            azione_g=array(1)
        else: azione_g=array(0)
    elif(qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(-1,st1)))>qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(0,st1)))):
            azione_g=array(-1)
    else: azione_g=array(0)

    #update the parameters (not sure if the cicle here is useful or correct)
    for u in range(0,10):
     delta=reward+gamma*qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(azione_g,st1)))-qfun(np.append(pars,np.append(azione[i],st1)))
     gradiente=der(qfun, np.append(pars,np.append(azione[i],st)), der_index=range(0,7))

     for t in range(0,7):
           pars[t]=pars[t]+alpha*delta*gradiente[t]

    returns=np.append(returns,returns[i-1]+azione[i]*ret[i])
```

Comment: What’s your problem exactly ? Does it seems too simple to be classified as RL ? Is it about nomenclature ? Does it matter ?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I was afraid that such a structure is too simple to be classified as RL and I was wondering if there's something I'm missing